# Working with Excel ranges and arrays

Tags: vb.net

In VBA, I can easily pull in an sheet\range into an array, manipulate, then pass back to the sheet\range. I'm having trouble doing this in VB.Net though.

Here's my code.

```
Rng = .Range("a4", .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
Dim SheetArray(,) As Object = DirectCast(Rng.Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault), Object(,))
For X As Integer = 0 To SheetArray.GetUpperBound(0)
    If IsNothing(SheetArray(X, 0)) Then Exit For
    SheetArray(X, 6) = SheetArray(X, 3)
    SheetArray(X, 7) = CDbl(SheetArray(X, 3).ToString) - CDbl(SheetArray(X, 1).ToString) - _
                                              CDbl(SheetArray(X, 7).ToString)
        For Y As Integer = 0 To 3
            SheetArray(X, Y * 2 + 1) = Math.Round(CDbl(SheetArray(X, Y * 2 + 1).ToString), 3)
        Next
        If Math.Abs(CDbl(SheetArray(X, 7).ToString)) > 0.1 Then _
            .Range(.Cells(X + 1, 1), .Cells(X + 1, 8)).Font.Color = -16776961
Next
```

I'm getting an error on the first `If IsNothing(SheetArray(X, 0)) Then Exit For`
line. It is telling me index is out of bounds of the array. Any idea why? The `SheetArray` object contains the data, but I just am not sure how to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `For` you have to loop from 0 to `Count - 1`:

```
For X As Integer = 0 To SheetArray.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
    '...
Next
```

That will fix your problem.